# React How to get width and height of props.chidren component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I want to create npm module for react. In this module i need to know height and width of components that passed into my component as props.children. I don't have control over that children. Currently i do that
 `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ref: this.myRef })}` 
inside render and then in other function i can get width and height this way

```
let myRect = this.myRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
if (!this.state.childSize.height && myRect.height !== 0) {
    var cSize = { height: myRect.height, width: myRect.width };
}
```

but it only works if children is passed like a dom element

```
<MyModuleComponent>
    <div>Hello world!</div>
</MyModuleComponent>
```

and didn't work if children is passed as a react component

```
<MyModuleComponent>
    <SomeChildComponent/>
</MyModuleComponent>
```

in this case `this.myRef.current` doesn't have getBoundingClientRect function.

How can i get width and height of children in this case?

Comment: `refs` are only attachable to DOM node. Take a look at `React.forwardRef`

Comment: do you need to know the dimensions of each child component separately or the sum they all take ?

Comment: @SmailGalijasevic I currently assume that child will be only one.

Comment: @Dupocas, so i need to force users of my module to create component with React.forwardRef function?

Comment: @AlexandrAccord if its only one than you could measure also the width and height of the parent minus margins and paddings ?

Comment: The problem is that `ref` isn't a prop, you can just pass it like you'd normally do. So f you need to attach a ref to a DOM node nested inside a custom component you need to pass this ref forward. `forwardRef((props,ref) => <ChildComponent {...props} ref={ref}) />)`